# Tinymce losing formatting on select all text and start typing

Tags: tinymce-4

I have create inline edit with tinymce and found one issue that it losing formatting on select all text and start typing.

I am using v4.5.7.

Please refer this image.

[image]

Here is my configuration settings.

```
$scope.paragraphelementInEditorOptions = {
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: 'textcolor colorpicker link lists paste',
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor bullist numlist undo redo',
    font_formats: font_names,
    fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 22px 24px 26px 28px 30px 32px 34px 36px",
    paste_as_text: true,
    forced_root_block: 'p',
    forced_root_block_attrs: {
        'class': 'myclass',
        'style': 'font-family: Open Sans; font-size: 32px;'
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is doing what it is designed to do.  When you select text and change the font the text is wrapped in a span.  If you then select all and delete you will also delete the span so the formatting also goes away.

Comment: @MichaelFromin: Can you please suggest me any solution regarding this. As I have succeeded to set default font-family and font-size using forced_root_block_attrs but I have found only one problem with that default bold text only.